# Putting a condition on CASE .. WHEN vs WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql

I want to know, writing `p.amount is null` at `case .. when` function is better, or writing it at `WHERE` clause?

**ONE:**

```
select *, 
     case when p.amount is null then '1'
          else (select count(1) 
                  from Money_paid mp 
                where mp.post_id = p.id and mp.user_id = :user_id limit 1)
     end paid
from Posts p 
where p.id = :post_id
```

**TWO:**

```
select *, 
      (select count(1) 
         from Money_paid mp 
           where mp.post_id = p.id and 
                 mp.user_id = :user_id and
                 p.amount is not null
        limit 1) paid
from Posts p 
where p.id = :post_id
```

So which one?

Comment: why using LIMIT 1 at all?

Comment: What are you trying to return?  The number that have paid or a flag?  In addition, the return values are not the same when `p.amount is null` (the first returns 1 and the second 0).

Comment: @GordonLinoff No I don't want the number that have paid, I just want to check is there any row? (just existing)

Comment: @Quassnoi I have used `LIMIT 1` because I just want to check only 1 row exist or not, I don't want to count anything.

Comment: @stack: that's not how the `LIMIT` works. If there are 1M relevant records in `money_paid`, all of them will be counted and returned as a single number in one record.

Comment: @Quassnoi Yes yes you are completely correct, Because I received `6` *(instead of `1`)* as `paid` column when I was testing. So may you please tell me what record are *relevant* ?

Comment: @stack: those which satisfy your `WHERE` conditions, of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether to use the `IS NULL` check in `COALESCE` or in the `WHERE` clause has no practical difference, however, you should replace `COUNT` with `EXISTS` if you only need one record checked:

```
SELECT  *,
        CASE WHEN p.amount IS NULL THEN 1
        ELSE
        EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    money_paid
        WHERE   post_id = p.id
                AND user_id = :user_id
        )
        END
FROM    posts p
WHERE   p.id = :post_id
```

Comment: Why `SELECT NULL ..` ? I want these outputs: `1` if the user has paid or the post is free or `0` if it isn't free and the user hasn't paid.

Comment: @stack: that's what `EXISTS` handles. It does not matter what's within `EXISTS`, you can use `SELECT *` or `SELECT 1` or pretty much anything you want. I use `SELECT NULL` because I'm used to it.

Comment: Just for my information, May you please tell me is possible implementing this via `join` instead of sub-query?

Comment: @stack: it is, but it will be less efficient

Answer (score 1):

Neither.  The better way to write this uses `exists`:

```
select p.*,
       (case when p.amount is null then 0  -- 0 seems more reasonable than 1
             when exists (select 1
                          from Money_paid mp
                          where mp.post_id = p.id and mp.user_id = :user_id
                         )
             then 1 else 0
        end) as IsPaidFlag
from Posts p 
where p.id = :post_id;
```

My tendency would be to go with the separate `case` condition.  The two versions  probably optimize to the same result.  However, having the external correlation could also confuse the optimizer.

Comment: In your query, if post is free then output is `0`, if post isn't free and user didn't pay it then output is `0`, if post isn't free and user paid it then `1`...! This structure is hard to handle it. I want this `1 , 0, 1` *( yours is `0, 0, 1`)*. So I can simply handle it like this: `if ($result['paid'] == 1) { show it } else { dont show it }`

Comment: @stack . . . As said in the answer, you can just put `1` for the first condition.  I just find that awkward.  And, the question itself is ambiguous about the value in that case.